# How to scrape text file from children of children sublinks with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the rap lyrics text documents and place them into an array from the following webpage (https://ohhla.com/all.html).

I am having a challenge figuring out how to write a script that will go to the lowest sublink and pull the text into an array.

My code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_site = "https://ohhla.com/all.html"

response = requests.get(base_site)

relative_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href]') if soup.select('a[href]') != None]

relative_urls = relative_urls[31:]

from urllib.parse import urljoin

full_urls = [urljoin(base_site, url) for url in relative_urls
```

each URL in the full_urls has sublinks that have the text file that I want to pull.

Does anyone have ideas on how to best approach writing a list comprehension?

Comment: This is best done with some kind of database, as far as I can see, it has many (1214) author, and then many album for each author, and many songs for each album.

sqlite should work well, you would probably need some kind of ORM though.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to separate anonymous and famous artists, parsing for them is different. I will show on the example of anonymous. But you will need to figure out how to store this information yourself. The easiest way seems to me to make a folder hierarchy.

```
response = requests.get('https://ohhla.com/all.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
links = ['https://ohhla.com/' + link.get('href') for link in soup.find('pre').find_all('a', {'href': True})]
anonymous_links = [link for link in links if 'anonymous' in link]
famous_links = [link for link in links if 'anonymous' not in link]
```

Output for famous:

```
['https://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_2pac.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_goodie.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_liks.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_asaprocky.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_azealia.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_eminem.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_beastieboys.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_otk.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_kane.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_goodie.html/', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_bigkrit.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_bigl.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_littlebrother.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_bigpun.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_bigsean.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_bizmark.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_blackeyedpeas.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_talib.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_BOB.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_icet.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_krs.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_brand.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_cypress.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_cypress.html#misc', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_ugk.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_getoboys.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_busta.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_camron.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_can_i_bus.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_cnn.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_goodie.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_j5.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_chiefkeef.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_childishgambino.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_koolkeith_two.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_E40.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_common.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_coflow.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_breeze.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_coup.html', 'https://ohhla.com/anonymoys/cymphoni/', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_cypress.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_eminem.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_dabrat.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_danjamowf.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_danny.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_dpg.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_dls.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_devinthedude.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_camron.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_ludacris.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_willsmith.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_djkhaled.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_three6.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_rundmc.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_dmx.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_dpg.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_oddfuture.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_mfdoom.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_drake.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_koolkeith_two.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_drdre.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_koolkeith_two.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_df.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_E40.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_oddfuture.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_coflow.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_eminem.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_epmd.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_eve.html', 'https://ohhla.com/YFA_houseofpain.html']
```

Now you need function to get links to txt:

```
def get_tracks(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    links = [url + link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')][5:]
    artist_name = url[:-1].split('/')[-1]
    albums = {}
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        album = link[:-1].split('/')[-1]
        tracks = [link + _link.get('href') for _link in soup.find_all('a')][5:]
        albums[album] = tracks
    return {artist_name: albums}
```

Now everything is ready to get all the albums\lyrics. I will display the first 100 artists as an example:

```
artists = []
for artist in anonymous_links[:100]:
    artists.append(get_tracks(artist))
print(artists)
```

OUTPUT is so long, just image:
[image]

Now that you have links to texts, you can get them using:

```
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find('pre').get_text()
```